# for loop speed comparison

Tags: performance, go, performance-testing

I was wondering how fast was the `len` operator in Go and I wrote a simple benchmark. My expectations were that by avoiding calling `len` during each loop iteration, the code would run faster, but it is in fact the opposite.

Here's the benchmark:

```
func sumArrayNumber(input []int) int {
    var res int
    for i, length := 0, len(input); i < length; i += 1 {
        res += input[i]
    }
    return res
}

func sumArrayNumber2(input []int) int {
    var res int
    for i := 0; i < len(input); i += 1 {
        res += input[i]
    }
    return res
}

var result int
var input = []int{3, 6, 22, 68, 11, -7, 22, 5, 0, 0, 1}

func BenchmarkSumArrayNumber(b *testing.B) {
    var r int
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        r = sumArrayNumber(input)
    }
    result = r
}

func BenchmarkSumArrayNumber2(b *testing.B) {
    var r int
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        r = sumArrayNumber2(input)
    }
    result = r
}
```

And here are the results:

```
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkSumArrayNumber-8       300000000                4.75 ns/op
BenchmarkSumArrayNumber2-8      300000000                4.67 ns/op
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  4.000s
```

I confirmed the resistent are consistents by doing the following:

- doubling the input array size roughly double the execution time per op. The speed difference scales with the length of the input array.
- exchanging the test order does not impact the results.

Why is the code checking len() at every loop iteration is faster?

Comment: This is unanswerable: The compiler is not obliged to not rewrite your code and may or may not optimize both version to the same code or even optimize that one you think to be slower to the faster one. Microbenchmarks are very hard to do and even harder to analyze (and thus are mostly a waste of time).

Comment: The call to len compiles to a field access in the slice header.

Comment: The compiler may detect that the value of `input` doesn't change and thus `len(input)` also doesn't change, and may only evaluate it once, giving no performance penalty at all, just as you experienced.

Answer (score 0):

One may argue that a difference of 0.08ns is not statistically relevant to say that one for-loop is faster than the other. You problably need to run the same test many times (more than 20 times at least), at that point you should be able to derive mean value and standard variation.

Moreover, there are many factors that can speedup the `len()` operator. Like CPU cache and compiler optimizations. I think that the most relevant factor in your specific example is that `len()` operator for slice and array just reads the `len` field in [slice](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/slice.go)'s data structure. Thus, it is O(1).

Comment: I did run it multiple times, maybe it was not clear but the speed difference was related to the length of the array

Comment: That was clear. But performance evaluation is about statistics, that requires enough samples in order to work properly. A single run of a benchmark, even with increasing array size, cannot tell which for-loop is the fastest, especially if the difference is only 0.08ns.

Comment: Arrays don't have headers like slices. `len()` for arrays is a compile time evaluation, as the length is part of the array type.